# Code runs well on Linux but gives a different output on Windows OS

Tags: c++, windows, linux, console, mingw

I have been wondering why the code below is giving me different output on Windows OS. Meanwhile, the same code works well on Ubuntu.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

string getname(void);
char getgender(string);
void setinfo(string,char);

int main()
{
    string customer = "";
    char gender;
    do {
        do{
            customer = getname();
        }while(customer =="");
        do{
            gender = getgender(customer);
            cout << "Gender in Main block is: " << gender << endl;
        }while(gender != 'm' && gender != 'f');
        setinfo(customer,gender);
        break;
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}

string getname(void)
{
    string name = "";
    cout <<"Please Enter your Name: " ;
    getline(cin,name);
    if(name == ""){
        cout << "Error: Name cannot be empty" <<  endl;
    }
    return name;
}

char getgender(string name)
{
    char gender;
    string strgender;
    cout << "Male / Female[m/f]: ";
    getline( cin,strgender);
    gender = strgender[0];
    strgender.clear();
    gender = tolower(gender);
    if(gender == 'm' || gender == 'f'){
        cout << "Gender in getgender() is: " << gender << endl;
        return gender;
    }
    else
        cout <<"Error: Must be m/ f" << endl;
}

void setinfo(string customer, char gender)
{
    string prefix;
    if(gender == 'm')
        prefix =  "Mr.";
    else
        prefix = "Ms/Mrs.";
    cout << "Hello " << prefix << " " << customer << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to TOWER HEIGHT" << endl;
}
```

On my Ubuntu machine, this code works fine. But when I compile and run it on Windows, I get different output and it keeps looping at getgender().

```
    Please Enter your Name: My Name
    Male / Female[m/f]: m
    Gender in getgender() is: m
    Gender in Main block is: ╕

    Male / Female[m/f]: f
    Gender in getgender() is: f
    Gender in Main block is: ╕

    Male / Female[m/f]:
```

Comment: On Windows, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#include <string>` ?  Copy pasted the code in VS Express 2010 - works fine... it doesn't loop the `getgender()` function. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using codeblocks with mingw32.

Comment: Minor note: Use `cerr <<` for errormessages.

Comment: Ok, I read a little about `cerr <<` but i thought it behaves the same way as `cout <<` that's why I didn't use it. I will try that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `getgender()` function falls off the end without returning a value when `gender` is set to an invalid value. This may be causing the compiler to generate bad code for that function; try fixing it by adding a "return 0" to the end.

You should turn on warnings on your Linux system, incidentally (by using the `-Wall` compiler flag). That would have made the problem immediately apparent:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘char getgender(std::string)’:
example.cpp:54: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff. I added the "return 0" so `getgender()` is able to  return to `gender` but it is still looping.

Comment: Ok, I got it now :) Forgot to change  `while(gender != 'm' || gender != 'f');`to `while(gender != 'm' && gender != 'f');` Thanks once again

Answer (score -2):

I compiled this code in MSVC 2010 and it works fine. What compiler are you using?

Comment: No, actually that'd break it worse. Your revised condition is always true.

Comment: -1: The answer is still wrong because `getgender` doesn't return anything after the else statement.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I added `return 0` after `esle` and it works well now. I was thinking after the program evaluate the `if` condition, it will `return gender` and terminate. Thanks once again :)